# How can I specifiy a substance in AERMOD?

Tags: models, air-pollution, pollution

Since I use OTHER as a pollutant ID, are there some parameters I could specify in order to get better results for dispersion of substance I am trying to model? eg. molecular weight or density?

Answer (score 2):

The `POLLUTID` key is used to specify some regular options.

Some examples:

- `PM2.5` can only evaluate averages greater than 24 hours (if you try to generate hourly averages it throws an error).
- `NO2` forces the use of options to simulate the conversion of NO<sub>x</sub> to NO<sub>2</sub>.
- `SO2` triggers the use of a 4-hour half-life for SO<sub>2</sub> decay in urban zones.

All pollutants (gases and particles) are treated similarly, regardless of their weight or molecular density.